# terminate a shell script without waiting for early parts of pipeline

Tags: bash, pipe

Consider the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
function long_running {
    for i in $(seq 1 10); do
        echo foo
        sleep 100
    done
}

long_running | head -n 1
```

This produces the expected output (one line "foo") but sleeps (for the specified 100 seconds) before terminating.  I would like the script to terminate immediately when head does.  How can I force bash to actually quit immediately?  Even changing the last line to

```
long_running | (head -n 1; exit)
```

or similar doesn't work; I can't get `set -e`, another common suggestion, to work even if I force a failure with, say, `(head -n 1; false)` or the like.

(This is a simplified version of my real code (obviously) which doesn't sleep; just creates a fairly complex set of nested pipelines searching for various solutions to a constraint problem; as I only need one and don't care which I get, I'd like to be able to make the script terminate by adding `head -n 1` to the invocation...)

Comment: The example is a bit misleading because the `sleep 100` is a subprocess of your script and has now way to tell its PID to other processes so they could kill it.
However you wrote that this `sleep 100` is actually a code block, so I suggest to rewrite this part of the example as FOR loop of `sleep 1`-s iterating 100 times.

Comment: Well, if I have any long running command (even a shell function) in that pipeline, it's still a subprocess.  But your example does create the same problem, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about sending the function to head like this -

```
#!/bin/bash
function long_running {
    for i in $(seq 1 10); do
        echo foo
        sleep 100
    done
}

head -n 1 <(long_running)
```

Obviously if you will increase the `-n` to a greater number, the sleep would kick in but would exit once head is completed.

Comment: This seems to work nicely, thanks!  It'd be nice if I could make a pipeline work too, but this seems fine.

Comment: (Also, I'm not quite clear why this works, though it does...)

Comment: Well the difference is that `pipe` gives the output of your `function` as a `STDIN` to `head` command. As a result it continues with `sleep` even after the `head` condition of 1 line is satisfied. With `process substitution`, a file is created and `head` is made to read that file. So as `head's` condition is satisfied your program exits but that doesn't mean it's over. The sleep continues to run in the background. This explanation may sound a little confusing but you can put `-x` like this `#!/bin/bash -x` or do a `ps -ef | grep sleep`.